# How to bundle custom NiFi processor which uses multiple bundles?

Tags: maven, hadoop, pom.xml, apache-nifi

I have written one Custom NiFi processor which uses some Hadoop classes, processes flow files and serializes flow files to and from Avro.

As per my knowledge

- to use Hadoop classes without packaging them as part of NAR I will need **nifi-hadoop-nar** bundle AND
- to serialize flow file contents to/from Avro, I will need RecordSetWriter and reader which are part of **record-serialization-services-api**.

Please correct me if my assumption is wrong.

I have written code, tested it and everything works as expected until I try to deploy NAR to NiFi.

When I deploy NAR and restart NiFi, it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nifi.serialization.RecordSetWriterFactory` exception.

My NAR's pom.xml looks like below:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my_company.is.data.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>custom-data-movement-processors</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-hadoop-nar</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <type>nar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-record-serialization-service-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and processor's pom.xml file looks like below:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-record-serialization-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        <dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-record-serialization-services-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        <dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Since I have marked `nifi-record-serialization-services-api` as `provided`, it doesn't get bundled in resulting NAR file.
Now I can do a quick fix and remove scope altogether and create NAR BUT then NiFi complains about next class not found error.

I would like to know:

- In NiFi project's code I found multiple nested bundles which have relation something like this nifi-nar-bundles -> nifi--bundle ->  . How to refer two bundles in my processor? As per my knowledge custom processor can have only one parent NAR and NAR = bundle?
- What is the preferred way to specify multiple NiFi bundles in pom.xml
- Ideally I do not want to bundle Hadoop related dependencies or NiFi dependencies in my NAR file. or is it mandetory in NiFi to bundle these dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <packaging>nar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-hadoop-nar</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <type>nar</type>
        </dependency>
```

should be enough to get in resulted nar `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`

attributes `Nar-Dependency-*`

```
Nar-Dependency-Id: nifi-hadoop-nar
Nar-Dependency-Group: org.apache.nifi
Nar-Dependency-Version: 1.5.0
```